# MySQL before delete trigger get other table value for condition

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to make a trigger to permanently delete transaction IF latest status is closed,

I tried my trigger code below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `prevent_delete_data` BEFORE DELETE ON `table_transaction` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE latest_track_status varchar(255);
    SELECT status INTO latest_track_status FROM table_transaction_track_status WHERE transaction_id = OLD.id ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1;
        IF (latest_track_status != closed) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE "45000"
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "You can\'t delete data if latest transaction status IS NOT closed";
        END IF;
END
```

but MySQl says `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3`

how did I solve that?

thanks

MySQL version `8.0.30`

Comment: closed is a string(I think) so should be single quoted. Also are you setting delimiters?

Comment: whoops, my bad. yes you're right I forgot to add delimeters. thank you @P.Salmon

Comment: *`WHERE transaction_id = OLD.id ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1`* Does `table_transaction_track_status.id` is not a primary key of this table? PS. Declaring the variable is excess, you may analyze the query output immediately.

Comment: @Akina the `table_transaction_track_status.id` is the primary key of this table, but the `transaction_id` column in `table_transaction_track_status` table is foreign key from `table_transaction`, thats why I put `WHERE transaction_id = OLD.id` because `table_transaction` hasMany `table_transaction_track_status` records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my bad where I forgot to add `DELIMITER` and closed inside IF condition must be string quoted `'closed'` thanks to @P.Salmon

EDIT:
this is the result I have done

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER `prevent_delete_data` BEFORE DELETE ON `table_transaction` FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DECLARE latest_track_status varchar(255);
        SELECT status INTO latest_track_status FROM table_transaction_track_status WHERE transaction_id = OLD.id ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1;
            IF (latest_track_status != 'closed') THEN
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE "45000"
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "You can\'t delete data if latest transaction status IS NOT closed";
            END IF;
    END
$$
```

Comment: Can you please update your updated query? It will help others.